# How to make a generic repository in Spring Boot that accepts an entity and few attributes and returns all the records based on the attributes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I want to make a generic repository that accepts the entity class and few attributes like start_date and end_date, etc and returns all the records in the table.

To fetch the results for a single entity using repository I will need to write a custom query. I am not sure how would I write a Custom query in a generic way for any entity that is passed and filter according to the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spring Data JPA you can declare your own shared repository interface with your own methods and avoid a custom query. The same approach is used by [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) to provide additional methods which are not present in [`Repsitory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html).

For example you can declare:

```
public interface SharedRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

  List<T> findByStartDateAndEndDate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate); 

}
```

Then extend from this new interface for your entities

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepisotry extends SharedRepository<Person, Long> {

}

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends SharedRepository<Room, Long> {

}
```

Both `PersonRepository` and `RoomRepository` will have `findByStartDateAndEndDate` method.

Comment: those only allow those specific attributes.

Comment: I need to write a query i think. Because the entity has actually a field called timestamp, which stores the date of the entry when it was created. I need to get the records whose timestamp is between start_date and end_date. And also some other fields like member_id(foreign key) @Karol

Comment: Yes @mavriksc. Those allow only specific attributes. I need to write custom query.

Comment: Try `findTimestampBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end)` due to [between is supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: Nested property is not my requirement. @KarolDowbecki

Answer (score 0):

[Spring now supports a kind of query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)

Service:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstname("Dave");
Example<Person> example = Example.of(person);
```

Repo Interface:

```
public interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
   <S extends T> S findOne(Example<S> example);
   <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
}
```

Comment: after seeing your comment on needing between dates. i don't think this will work.

Comment: you could use this and then just stream().filter by date... not the best solution as it would be best to do all in repo, but having to null check properties and add Criteria is kind of a hassle too.